# Issue about displaying circle on an existing image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, draw

When I tried to illustrate the feature clusters in the image as the color circles. After I imported two libraries: I imported these two related libraries:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
```

I used the code like the following:

```
 > draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img1) draw.ellipse((x-10, y-10, x+10, y+10),
 > fill=(255,0,0,0))
```

The error I get is as the following:

```
File "assi_6.python", line 85, in main
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img1)
  File "/Users/qdai/anaconda/envs/vision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 284, in Draw
    return ImageDraw(im, mode)
  File "/Users/qdai/anaconda/envs/vision/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 59, in __init__
    im.load()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute ‘load’
```

Comment: has my answer solved your problem?

Comment: Yes your answer solved my problem. Thank you! Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning `numpy.ndarray` in the error message gives a hint that the object `img1` is not an image as PIL needs it for its methods.

Try to create/load `img1` using PIL methods to avoid that error.